# How to get the unicode characters for sequences: CTRL+B, CTRL+L, ALT+K, etc... Got for some not all?

Tags: php

I am writing an application which interfaces with Nano in linux. Nano requires to receive control sequences to save/exit/and work with the files (`^G ^R ^O ^Y ^K`, etc...)

I figured out the unicode for `^X = U+0018` by blind chance. I enter it into GEdit with CTRL+SHIFT+U+0018 and press enter. This gives me the character that I can copy/paste. But as I want my application to be complete I wish to be able to have a complete list of unicode chars for combinations of ctrl/alt/shift + any other key.

I tried to do this by connecting between shells with netcat and pressing (for example) CTRL+B and seeing what appears on the other side. This works for some of them, not for all as the terminal 'interprets' some escapes before being able to send through netcat.

I'm offering a bounty now as have spent a number of hours trying to work it out with no luck, what I want is either:

- A) a method to acquire all the unicodes for `CTRL/ALT/SHIFT + key combinations` ( E.g. `CTRL+G` = what unicode)?
- B) a comprehensive list that includes the ones I have noted above.

Comment: Unicode is standard of **printable** characters, not for some console-mode sequences, so sorry unless I'm mistaken your questions seems a bit off to me...

Comment: Tomas, I need to map "whatever is sent to the console" when pressing control characters like ctrl+k to simulate them. So far the only thing that has worked is figuring out the unicode, creating the character, and passing it inside the program to the console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the [`showkey`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_showkey.htm) command

Hint - `X` is the `0x18`th letter of the alphabet:

```
^@   0x00
^A   0x01
...
^X   0x18
^Y   0x19
^Z   0x1A
^[   0x1B
^\   0x1C
^]   0x1D
^^   0x1E
^_   0x1F
```

The more complex combinations actually appear as a *series* of characters (for instance <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> is `^[^[[13~` - 6 characters).

Note that all of these are really ascii.

Comment: But then how do you find ALT+F3 or CTRL+F9 etc? And ALT+CTRL at same time plus other letters?

Comment: @OBV: type `showkey` into your shell prompt - you might need to be `sudo`

Comment: How did you get the ^[^[[13~ ? When I tried using showkey, it gave me: ^[01;3R

Comment: @OBV: It depends on your settings in some way, I imagine. I think my keymap is slightly borked anyway, since I'm testing through putty. At any any rate, if the keys you push work to control `nano`, then the thing spat out by `showkey` will be correct.

Comment: OK thanks, ill wait and see if get anymore answers but I think this does the job for the main part.

Comment: will ward bounty when can

Answer (score 0):

Go on Windows and start the character map in the accesories. When you press on a letter, the bottom left corner should have the unicode equivalent for that character.